# SQL Cursor to join periods of dates into single row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, gaps-and-islands

My goal is to have a single row by id.

Now I have multiple rows like this for each one

For example user number 001 has this:

| Ini Date | End Date | Qnty |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-02 | 2023-01-02 | 1.0000 |
| 2023-01-03 | 2023-01-03 | 1.0000 |
| 2023-01-04 | 2023-01-04 | 1.0000 |
| 2023-01-05 | 2023-01-05 | 1.0000 |
| 2023-01-06 | 2023-01-06 | 1.0000 |

My goal is to when the Ini.Date of the following row is the next day it update the end date and sums the Qnt.

My expected ouput would be:

| Ini Date | End Date | Qnty |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-02 | 2023-01-06 | 5.0000 |

Can anyone please point me in the right direction ?

Comment: What had you tried? just use aggregate function might get your expectation result

Comment: So you only want to sum `Qnty` for consecutive dates? I strongly recommend breaking up your  ranges so you include multiple cases - end date > ini date (unless they're always equal, in which case why have two columns?), and an ini date more than a day > previous ini date. This way we know how to solve the problem when the data doesn't match the single case you've included so far.

Comment: In addition to what D-Shih and Aaron Bertrand wrote, I suggest you supply your sample data as DLL+DML statements, so that when someone attempts to answer your question, they can copy it directly into their own test environment and actually write a solution that works, with minimal effort.

Comment: ^ [db<>fiddle](https://sqlblog.org/fiddle) is great for that...

Comment: This is a "gaps and islands" problem - a term you can use for searching the internet to find discussions about solving them and code to compute them.

Answer (score 0):

You can try code like below. Explanation is in the comments.

**Note** : You will need to use separate loop for each user.

```
-- Variables to hold current and next dates
DECLARE @CurrentDate date, @NextDate date

-- Initially select min date as current date
SELECT @CurrentDate = MIN(IniDate) FROM @TempTable;
-- Select next date as min date which is greater than current selected min date
SELECT @NextDate = MIN(IniDate) FROM @TempTable WHERE IniDate > @CurrentDate;

-- If next date is null then we reach at the end of dataset
WHILE (@NextDate IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN

    -- Check if we add 1 day in current day is same as next day then update current row and delete row with next date
    IF DATEADD(day, 1, @CurrentDate) = @NextDate
    BEGIN

        -- Update EndDate & Quantity with current date
        UPDATE t1
        SET t1.EndDate = t2.IniDate,
            t1.Qnty = t1.Qnty + t2.Qnty
        FROM @TempTable t1 
            JOIN @TempTable t2 
                ON t1.EndDate = @CurrentDate AND t2.IniDate = @NextDate

        -- Delete next date row
        DELETE FROM @TempTable WHERE IniDate = @NextDate

    END

    -- Set current date as next date
    SET @CurrentDate = @NextDate;
    -- Recalculate next date
    SELECT @NextDate = MIN(IniDate) FROM @TempTable WHERE IniDate > @CurrentDate;

END
```

---

Here is the updated code which will work for multiple users as well. Added JOIN with UserId.

```
-- Variables to hold current and next dates
DECLARE @CurrentDate date, @NextDate date

-- Initially select min date as current date
SELECT @CurrentDate = MIN(IniDate) FROM @TempTable;
-- Select next date as min date which is greater than current selected min date
SELECT @NextDate = MIN(IniDate) FROM @TempTable WHERE IniDate > @CurrentDate;

-- If next date is null then we reach at the end of dataset
WHILE (@NextDate IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN

    -- Check if we add 1 day in current day is same as next day then update current row and delete row with next date
    IF DATEADD(day, 1, @CurrentDate) = @NextDate
    BEGIN

        -- Update EndDate & Quantity with current date
        -- Use join with UserId as well
        UPDATE t1
        SET t1.EndDate = t2.IniDate,
            t1.Qnty = t1.Qnty + t2.Qnty
        FROM @TempTable t1 
            JOIN @TempTable t2 
                ON t1.EndDate = @CurrentDate AND t2.IniDate = @NextDate AND t1.UserId = t2.UserId

        -- Delete next date row with respective UserId
        -- Add condition t1.IniDate <> t2.IniDate so that row does not have join with itself
        DELETE t2
        FROM @TempTable t1 
            JOIN @TempTable t2 
                ON t1.IniDate <> t2.IniDate AND t1.EndDate = t2.IniDate AND t1.UserId = t2.UserId

    END

    -- Set current date as next date
    SET @CurrentDate = @NextDate;
    -- Recalculate next date
    SELECT @NextDate = MIN(IniDate) FROM @TempTable WHERE IniDate > @CurrentDate;

END
```

Answer (score -1):

This is a classic *gaps-and-islands* problem.

There are a number of solutions. Here is one common one:

- Use `LAG` to identify rows which have gaps.
- Use a windowed conditional `COUNT` to number the groups between the gaps with an ID.
- Group by that ID.

```sql
WITH PrevValues AS (
    SELECT *,
      IsNewGroup = CASE WHEN LAG(t.[End Date]) OVER (ORDER BY t.[End Date])
                        < DATEADD(day, -1, t.[Ini Date]) THEN 1 END
    FROM YourTable t
),
Groups AS (
    SELECT *,
      GroupId = COUNT(t.IsNewGroup) OVER (ORDER BY t.[Ini Date])
    FROM PrevValues t
)
SELECT
  [Ini Date] = MIN(t.[Ini Date]),
  [End Date] = MAX(t.[End Date]),
  Qnty = SUM(t.Qnty)
FROM Groups t
GROUP BY
  t.GroupId;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7b30e0512ac65975acfea0357bd0ba87)